# The logic of building this update statement is confusing me

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table called Targets

```
a_LOG a_RF a_GNB a_SVC b_LOG b_RF b_GNB b_SVC a_1st a_2nd a_3rd a_4th b_1st b_2nd b_3rd b_4th
22    83   97    83    32    77   95    86    GNB   RF    SVC   LOG   GNB   SVC   RF    LOG
```

It is split into 4 parts

first the outcome of 4 alogirthms Try 1

```
a_LOG a_RF a_GNB a_SVC
22    83   97    83
```

second  the outcome of 4 alogirthms Try 2

```
 b_LOG b_RF b_GNB b_SVC
 32    77   95    86
```

third  the order of the Try 1 algorithms

```
 a_1st a_2nd a_3rd a_4th
 GNB   RF    SVC   LOG
```

forth the order of the Try 2 algorithms

```
 b_1st b_2nd b_3rd b_4th
 GNB   SVC   RF    LOG
```

As you can see both trials have the same orders of algorithms

but in the 1st try the algorithms RF and SVC have the same values 83. so they ordered alphabetically

RF 2nd and SVC 3rd

This is making both trials look different `GNB > RF > SVC > LOG` the first and `GNB > SVC > RF > LOG` the second trial

I wonder how can I make both trials results the same  `GNB > SVC > RF > LOG` and `GNB > SVC > RF > LOG`

I built this script so you can get some data in the repeatable table

```
declare @T as table(a_LOG int, a_RF int,a_GNB int,a_SVC int,b_LOG int,b_RF int,b_GNB int,b_SVC int,a_1st varchar(9), a_2nd varchar(9), a_3rd varchar(9), a_4th varchar(9), b_1st varchar(9), b_2nd varchar(9), b_3rd varchar(9), b_4th varchar(9))

insert into @T values (22, 83, 97, 83, 32, 77, 95, 86, 'GNB', 'RF', 'SVC', 'LOG', 'GNB', 'SVC', 'RF', 'LOG'),
(57, 93, 34, 67, 44, 88, 44, 82, 'RF', 'SVC', 'LOG', 'GNB', 'RF', 'SVC', 'GNB', 'LOG'),
(60, 40, 80, 90, 65, 95, 65, 95, 'SVC', 'GNB', 'LOG', 'RF', 'RF', 'SVC', 'GNB', 'LOG')
```

I started with this approach but it was't ptacticale as I have to build more than 100 case statement in my update

```
update @T
set 
b_1st = case when a_LOG >= a_RF and b_LOG = b_RF then a_1st else b_1st end
             when a_LOG >= a_GNB and b_LOG = b_GNB then a_1st else b_1st end
             when a_LOG >= a_SVC and b_LOG = a_SVC then a_1st else b_1st end
             when a_LOG >= a_GNB and b_LOG = b_GNB then a_1st else b_1st end
```

### Edit

I want them to be order desc. but when 2 algorithms have the same value then the order should depend on the other trial, so it matches the other trial's order if possible

Comment: The rules are not clear. Do you want to find an ordering of algorithms such that in both trials results are in non-decreasing order? What if there exists no such ordering of algorithms?

Comment: I want them to be order desc. but when 2 algorithms have the same value then the order should depend on the other trial, so it matches the other trial's order if possible

Comment: This table is completely denormalized. You should store repeating pieces of information in separate rows not separate columns

Comment: @Charlieface this is not for business, it is for academic research, normalisation is not an important thing compare to the ease of use to the researchers